# Change CSV records sequentially

Tags: text-processing, sed, csv-simple

I want to replace the text sequentially in a file.

The file's contents are:

```
1,01-JUN-2016,ABC
2,01-JUN-2016,ABC
3,01-JUN-2016,ABC
4,01-JUN-2016,ABC
5,01-JUN-2016,ABC
6,02-JUN-2016,ABC
7,02-JUN-2016,ABC
8,02-JUN-2016,ABC
9,02-JUN-2016,ABC
10,02-JUN-2016,ABC
11,02-JUN-2016,ABC
12,02-JUN-2016,ABC
13,02-JUN-2016,ABC
14,02-JUN-2016,ABC
```

I want this to be modified as below:

```
1,01-JUN-2016,ABC1
2,01-JUN-2016,ABC2
3,01-JUN-2016,ABC3
4,01-JUN-2016,ABC4
5,01-JUN-2016,ABC5
6,02-JUN-2016,ABC6
7,02-JUN-2016,ABC7
8,02-JUN-2016,ABC1
9,02-JUN-2016,ABC2
10,02-JUN-2016,ABC3
11,02-JUN-2016,ABC4
12,02-JUN-2016,ABC5
13,02-JUN-2016,ABC6
14,02-JUN-2016,ABC7
```

Answer (score 1):

using awk

```
awk '$0=$0 (NR-1)%7+1' file
```

or

```
awk '{print (NR-1)%7+1}' file
```

Basically the subtract 1 is to start on the number zero.
The modulo 7 is loop back every seven lines.
The plus 1 is due to the fact the 7 mod 7 is 0 which is not what we want to start on, we want to start on 1 so we +1.

Comment: where does the OP say they want to use the record number and not the first field?

Answer (score 0):

```awk
$ awk -F, 'FNR < 8 { print $0$1 }; FNR > 7 {print $0($1-7)}' arvind.txt 
1,01-JUN-2016,ABC1
2,01-JUN-2016,ABC2
3,01-JUN-2016,ABC3
4,01-JUN-2016,ABC4
5,01-JUN-2016,ABC5
6,02-JUN-2016,ABC6
7,02-JUN-2016,ABC7
8,02-JUN-2016,ABC1
9,02-JUN-2016,ABC2
10,02-JUN-2016,ABC3
11,02-JUN-2016,ABC4
12,02-JUN-2016,ABC5
13,02-JUN-2016,ABC6
14,02-JUN-2016,ABC7
```

For line numbers < 8, print the entire line followed by the first field.  For line numbers > 7, print the entire line followed by the value of the first field minus 7.

Note, `FNR` is the number of input records that `awk` has seen in the current input file so far.  `FNR` is an `awk` built-in variable.  It has **nothing** (beyond co-incidence) to do with the values you have in the first field of your input file.

BTW, if you run this with multiple input files and you want a cumulative line-count for all input files (rather than a separate line count for each file), use `NR` rather than `FNR`.

Comment: Why are you using `$1` instead of `FNR` in the print statements? Where does OP say they want to use the Values from the first field?

Comment: where do they say they don't?  Either FNR or $1 work **here** because they're (coincidentally) the same value for the provided sample input.

Comment: They don't say either, but I didn't assume they cared about either. As far as i can tell from the limited information they just wanted to add 1-7 repeatedly to the end of the last field. FNR is always going to be correct to produce this pattern, there is a possibility that $1 won't be.

Comment: exactly my point.  and AFAICT they wanted the value of $1 or $1 - 7 (or even ($1-1) % 7 +1) added to the end of each line, and using FNR isn't always going to be correct (It'll only be correct where FNR==$1).  I probably should have used `awk '{print $0(($1 - 1) % 7 +1)}' arvind.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your quick inputs. I need this only for 1 file so will go with your solution.

Comment: please accept the answer you like best by clicking on the big tick ✔ to the left of the answer.  acceptance and upvotes are how thanks are given on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk -F, '$1 <=7 { print $0$1 }; $1 > 7 {print $0($1-7)}' filename
```